# Detect XMPP Message is read/unread with Openfire

Tags: ios, xmpp, chat, openfire, xmppframework

I'm developing a chat app that use XMPPFramework and Openfire Server. Is there any way to detect if a message is read or unread?
I'm heard about XEP-0184, but it's only the message delivery (received or not).

Comment: No, it's impossible: "read" a message means that an human it's reading a line, basically only an human can confirm that. Whatsapp double checks are gray when recived by server and blue when the message it's recived on destination device.

Comment: Oh, it is "Seen", like facebook or Skype, I want to check if user saw it (or it's displayed on screen)

Comment: You need a custom XMPP extension to support this.

Comment: Of course I agree with @MickaëlRémond: custom XMPP extension that notify when it's displayed on screen and this depends on implementation

Comment: issue resolved?

Comment: Can't do with XMPP. I saved the receive message in sqlite, if user read, delete it, the others is unread

Answer (score 1):

XEP-0184 (Delivery Receipt) used to ensure that message reached to the end user (user is online). For display notification you can use XEP-0085 (ChatStateEvent) or XEP-0022 (MessageEvent). Though XEP-0022 is deprecated and XEP-0085 is recommended.

Comment: I think XEP-0085 can not resolve my problem. XEP-0085 only notify the message status before it was sent (user is composing or not). I found XEP-0333 may helpful for me. I'll try this.

Comment: Ok. thats fine :)

Comment: And I realised that XEP-0333 used to send the message status when both user is online, the archiveMessage didn't save the status of the message, so I can't find the unread message count like Fb or Skype does

Answer (score 0):

How I achieved this by sending a *special message* when user opens the Unread chat.

And when the user receives that *special message*, it will get to know that the message has been read by other user.

Special Message should be unique: so that you can put a check on if it is received then it means message has been read.

Comment: This is not what the OP means. You are talking about letting the SENDER know if the message was read. The OP wants to know how the RECEIVER of MANY messages can be told how many UNREAD messages they still have in their queue/inbox.